# Is there a way to stop pygame application from blocking device from entering sleep mode on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I’m developing a tamagotchi - like pygame application (packaged with pyinstaller)that scans for wifi networks every 30 seconds and “eats” them. One of my users has informed me that my application blocks macOS devices from entering sleep mode while it’s running. Is there a way to allow devices to enter sleep mode even if the app is running?

I have attempted to ask chatGPT for a solution, but they all had syntax or other errors.